# Filtering dpkg logs in syslog-ng

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, syslog-ng, filter

I am new to `syslog-ng`, and I am setting a `syslog-ng`, where I am receiving logs of `syslog`, `auth.log` and `dpkg.log`. Although I was able to get the logs for `syslog` and `auth.log`, but I am unable to write the `dpkg` logs to seperate file and it is getting written in both `dpkg` log files as well as `syslog` log files.
The configuration file for the server is as follows:

```
options {
    create_dirs(yes);
    owner(root);
    group(root);
    perm(0640);
    dir_owner(root);
    dir_group(root);
    dir_perm(0750);
};

source s_dl {
   network (
   transport("tcp")
   port(3993)
);
};

filter f_dpkg{
    tags("dpkg");
};

destination d_host-specific {

  file("/var/log/servers/$HOST/$YEAR/$MONTH/$HOST-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.log");
};

destination d_syslog {
        file("/var/log/servers/$HOST/$YEAR/$MONTH/$HOST-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY-syslog.log");
};

destination d_dpkg {
    file("/var/log/servers/$HOST/$YEAR/$MONTH/$HOST-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY-dpkg.log");
};

log {
    source(s_dl);
    filter(f_auth);
    destination(d_host-specific);
};

log {
    source(s_dl);
    filter(f_syslog3);
    destination(d_syslog);
 };

log{
    source(s_dl);
    filter(f_dpkg);
    destination(d_dpkg);
};
```

The configuration file for the syslog-ng client is as follows:

```
 source s_dpkg {
   file('/var/log/dpkg.log'); tags('dpkg'));
 };
 destination d_net { tcp("192.168.48.15" port(3993)); };
 filter f_tag { tags("dpkg"); };
 log { source(s_src); filter(f_auth); destination(d_net);};
 log { source(s_src); filter(f_syslog3); destination(d_net);};
 log { source(s_dpkg); filter(f_test); destination(d_net);};
```

Can anybody point me out where my mistake is or what should be the proper way to get the details.
Note: I need to use the same port for accepting all logs of a single host as I cannot keep on adding new ports to accept different logs from the  same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the tag that your client adds to dpkg messages is not transferred to the server side (because it's not a part of the original message).

Also, it seems to me that this whole tagging is needed because the original dpkg logs do not fill the PROGRAM field of the syslog messages. So the easiest way to solve the problem IMHO is:

- Use the program-override("dpkg") option in the source s_dpkg on the client ( https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-source-file.html#idm45439656585216 ) to properly set the PROGRAM field in the dpkg messages
- On the server, use the program("dpkg") filter instead of the tags filter.

HTH